# Install ZendFramwork 2 on XAMPP on Windows

Tags: php, git, zend-framework, composer-php, php-5.3

I am bit confused with installation of ZendFramework2. I am not getting clear step to install ZF2. I have XAMPP installed on my windows machine. I have ZF2 and Zend framework Skeleton  downloaded.

Is there any need to clone zendskeleton with GIT if I have zip of skeleton available?  If yes then please tell me why?

What is a need to of composer? Please tell me how to install on windows?

Can any on suggest any web page to help me out with zendframwork 2 installation.

Comment: you can find the instruction here http://www.w3programmers.com/install-zend-framework-2-on-your-wamp-and-xampp-server/

Comment: @Harish: I am not able to install composer

Comment: are you getting any error of openssl? if yes than please enable it in php.ini

Comment: No it is different error. "Https://getcomposer.org/version File could not be downloaded. Failed to open stream....". and openssl is enable in php.ini. Can you please add new answer to this question...So later on i can accept is if it works.

Comment: are you using a proxy server?

Comment: please set http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#http-proxy-or-http-proxy

Comment: possible duplicate of [ZendSkeleton Issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377539/zendskeleton-issues) - you should really not open the same question twice, with the later one having the BETTER description. You can edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

here is a tutorial for all PHP Zend Developer who wants to install zend framework on their windows system.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/zend-framework-from-scratch/

Comment: I need ZF2 to be installed

Answer (score 0):

please check your php version for zend framework 2 it should be 5.3.5 or upper also check composer file permission and `allow_url_fopen = On` in php.ini

Comment: PHP 5.4 and allow_url_fopen is On in php.ini file

Comment: I think composer is not installed that is why it is giving error. Do I have to manually install it?