# ZendSkeleton Issues

Tags: git, zend-framework2, composer-php

I have downloaded .zip for zendskeleton and it is having composer.phar and composer.json.
when I run below given command in Git CLI from zendskeleton folder it gives some error.

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

Error:

$ php composer.phar self-update

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: failed
  to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
   not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection fai
  led because connected host has failed to respond.

self-update

```
php composer.phar install
```

Error:

$ php composer.phar install
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommend
ed to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version
.
Loading composer repositories with package information

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: fai
  led to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party
   did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
   failed because connected host has failed to respond.

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-c
ustom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--opt
imize-autoloader]

```
Edit: with php composer.phar update
```

$ php composer.phar update
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommend
ed to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version
.
Loading composer repositories with package information

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: fai
  led to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party
   did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
   failed because connected host has failed to respond.

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock]
 [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [
-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]

Comment: have you tried `php composer.phar update` ?

Comment: what will happen with this command?

Comment: This will update the dependencies to latest version.

Comment: not working...see i have updated my quest with it as well

Comment: try expanding the process timeout of your composer json by adding this, `"config":{ "process-timeout":4000}`. or try by exceeding the `default_socket_timeout` time of php.ini file. may be its a host issue.

Comment: I have added config in json and default_socket_timeout = 60 but still same issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39261/discussion-between-paulraj-and-poonam-bhatt)

Comment: not having access to chat page ... not possible for me

Comment: this error may happen due to network errors. Check if the proxy or firewall settings are okay, and use ping to detect where the connection is blocked.

Comment: how can i check proxy and firewall settigns

Comment: i have ping the blocked ...it giving replay

Comment: can you run `php composer.phar diagnose` and see the output for the problem ?

Comment: yes...I did that as well

Comment: Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommend
ed to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version
.
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.jso
n" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: A connection attempt fai
led because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
 or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Checking composer.json: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version:


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: failed
  to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
   not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection fai
  led because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: enable the SSL extension if not in php.ini file. `extension=php_openssl.dll` and restart the server.

Comment: it is alreday enable and showing in php info

Comment: the problem is with your proxy settings then. check this page to change your proxy and try with that. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268093/composer-cannot-download-files)

Comment: FYI, to configure composer behind http proxy, (http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#http-proxy-or-http-proxy)

Comment: add answer to this question so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred due to the proxy settings. You need to set the http_proxy environment variables since you are on windows OS. You can set the environment variables as below,

```
set http_proxy=<your_http_proxy:proxy_port>
set https_proxy=<your_https_proxy:proxy_port>
```

To configure composer behind http proxy, [Http Proxy](http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#http-proxy-or-http-proxy)